# Eliminar carpetas según la hora BAT

Tags: windows, script, batch, tiempo

Tengo un script que elimina carpetas de una ruta especifica, donde su hora de modificación sea mayor a 4 horas desde que se ejecuta el script. Actualmente funciona pero con el formato de 24 horas. Cuando el servidor o PC donde quiero ejecutar tiene el formato de 12 horas, está borrando todo.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como modificar esto le agradeceria, voy pasando el script:

```
@echo off setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Establece la ruta de la carpeta a verificar set "targetDir=C:\CarpetaPrueba"

:: Obtiene la hora actual en formato de horas for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('echo %time%') do (
    set /A "currentHour=%%a"
    set /A "currentMinute=%%b" )

:: Convierte la hora actual a minutos set /A "currentTimeInMinutes=(currentHour*60)+currentMinute"

:: Define el límite de tiempo en horas (4 horas) set /A "timeLimitInHours=4" set /A "timeLimitInMinutes=(timeLimitInHours*60)"

:: Recorre las carpetas en la ruta especificada for /d %%D in ("%targetDir%\*") do (
    :: Obtiene la hora de modificación de la carpeta
    for %%I in ("%%D") do (
        set "folderTime=%%~tI"
        for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ("!folderTime:~11,5!") do (
            set /A "folderHour=%%a"
            set /A "folderMinute=%%b"
        )
    )
    
    :: Convierte la hora de modificación de la carpeta a minutos
    set /A "folderTimeInMinutes=(folderHour*60)+folderMinute"
    
    :: Calcula la diferencia en minutos entre la hora actual y la hora de modificación de la carpeta
    set /A "timeDifference=currentTimeInMinutes-folderTimeInMinutes"
    
    :: Verifica si la diferencia es mayor al límite establecido (4 horas)
    if !timeDifference! geq !timeLimitInMinutes! (
        echo Eliminando carpeta: "%%D"
        rmdir /s /q "%%D"
    ) )

echo Limpieza de carpetas completada. endlocal
```

Comment: ¿Ese script de verdad corre?

Comment: Si, lo he probado localmente y si me funciona cuando mi PC la tengo en formato de 24 horas, al pasarlo a formato de 12 horas, es donde borra todo.